# How to fix VSCode "Include file not found" green squiggles under C++ includes inside inactive #ifdefs?

Tags: c++, include, visual-studio-code, conditional-compilation

I'm working on a C++ program for Linux and Windows and for Windows-specific functionality requiring Windows.h and psapi.h, I'm seeing "Include file not found in include directory" green squiggles in VSCode on Linux despite _WINDOWS not being defined:

[image: Include file not found in include directory]

Is there a way to fix this properly? A hack fix I have found to work is to create empty files Windows.h and psapi.h in folder /usr/local/include/windows_potemkin_village and then add that folder to includePath in c_cpp_properties.json.

Comment: Have you considered artificial colour blindness?